# Join/lookup on dataframe 1 column with data in string of dataframe 2 - Python

Tags: python, join, lookup

So I have two dataframes:

dfFruit:

```
    Fruit   Colour
 0   Apple  Red()()()
 1   Apple  Green<>
 2   Apple  Blue ()()
 3   Orange Red()()()
 4   Orange Green<>
 5   Orange Blue ()()
```

DfColour:

```
  Colour Count
0 Red   100
1 Green 200
2 Blue  500
```

I want to create an extra column in dfFruit containing the Count found in dfColour. Is there an efficient way of doing the look up based on the similar but non-identical 'Colour' columns e.g. some lookup like Red in Red()()().

This is a simplified example, imagine there is a million rows of data or something so I don't want to iterate over the dataframes.